# What can be the reason behind the removal of questions at the same time?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I was going through my reputation changes one day and found out this:

[image]

Now, I am in doubt whether why these questions were removed and I remembered that these questions were fairly accepted and were neither heavily downvoted nor flagged. In fact, some of these questions received comments.

If these questions were underrated or low quality questions then how do they all got removed at the same time? Is it some kind of automated process on Stack Overflow that did this?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All 4 posts were deleted by the system (aka [the roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)):

> deleted by Community♦ Jan 20 at 2:44 (RemoveDeadQuestions)

Because it is a batch process that runs every few days, the deletions all took place at the same time even though the 4 questions had been posted on different days in December.

From the linked help centre article:

> The Community user will automatically delete old abandoned/dead questions in the following circumstances:
>
> **If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked

Each of these 4 questions qualified.

Also see [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)